# Premature end of file parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I use this method to validate the xml file that stores some config info:

```
public static boolean isXmlFileWellFormed(File xmlFile) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "isXmlFileWellFormed({0})", xmlFile);
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.parse(xmlFile);
        return true; // document well formed
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Xml file is not well-formed: {0}", ex);
        try {
            FileUtils.streamToFile(new FileInputStream(xmlFile), "c:\\backup.xml");
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "backup not created");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

it validates the xml file well, it looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mountedFolders>

<folder path="C:\tmp\prezentacka\" recursively="false">
        <document key="1636_0001_pdf_1.png;539777;1338204039646">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="faktura.pdf;1102305;1336552599405">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="prva strana_1361268270589.JPEG;276888;1361269977428">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    </folder>
<folder path="C:\tmp\one2\" recursively="false">
        <document key="1636_0001.pdf;280700;1336569165030">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="1636_0001_pdf_1.png;539777;1338204039646">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="1636_0001_pdf_2.png;565609;1338204041562">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="1637_0001.pdf;121031;1336569168739">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="faktura.pdf;1102305;1336552599405">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    </folder>
<folder path="C:\tmp\" recursively="false">
        <document key="faktura1.pdf;637590;1340007249059">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    <document key="LicZmluva.pdf;41164;1340016186796">
            <state>NEW</state>
        </document>
    </folder>
</mountedFolders>
```

meybe its not totaly well formed but it should be valid. Actualy, this xml is the backup.xml saved after the parsing method crashes in catch block of code with error

```
[INFO] stderr.run: [Fatal Error] .mounted:1:1: Premature end of file.
[WARNING] XmlUtils.isXmlFileWellFormed: Xml file is not well-formed:
```

Can it somehow relate to threads?
thanks everyone

**UPDATE**
I created error handler for document builder but it says again

> fatal error: premature end of file

Comment: Well that doesn't look like it's hitting your catch statement at all - there's nothing saying "Xml file is not well-formed"

Comment: yes it is written next in the log, i can update it, but the log stderr.run is weird to me, dont now why it is logged like this

Comment: I would assume that the `.mounted:1:1` means line 1, column 1 in the file `.mounted`. So, in other words, it looks like `.mounted` is an empty file. Are you sure the file name is correct? Are you sure it's not looking for the file in the wrong directory? Have you opened the file and verified that it is not empty?

Comment: paste the entire exception. You are logging not-well-formed for ANY exception. You are masking the real exception.

Comment: yes, I am working with it in the app, every time the user adds new folder to app, the file is validated and parsed to document, than the document is edited and saved to file.. but sometimes it crashes, not always, after save the xml is valid, some parts of the app works in backround thread

Comment: @srini.venigalla i tried but the most I can get from them is the premature end of file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad, the access to file was not [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) and that looks like the cause of the exception. Thanks all for help